# Issue with MoveIt Tutorials

Tags: moveit, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I try to launch the tutorials from MoveIt, but it's not working, I get this error message :

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_moveit_tutorials/kinematic_model_tutorial]: can't locate node [kinematic_model_tutorial] in package [pr2_moveit_tutorials]
```

I have installed ROS and moveit with instructions from

- [ROS] [www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu)
- [MoveIt] moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/Installation

not from sources.

I tried to install from sources but I had another issue : RViz refused to launch, it throw me this error :

```
rviz: /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreSceneManager.cpp :807 : virtual Ogre::SceneNode* Ogre::SceneManager::createSceneNode(): the assertion « mSceneNodes.find(sn->getName()) == mSceneNodes.end() » has failed.
```

Can anybody help me?

THanks!

Ben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63227/issue-with-moveit-tutorials/) by [BenjaminV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4952/benjaminv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry about this, this is an error in our installation process for the tutorials package. It will be corrected in the next release. In the meantime, you can get the package from source and run the launch files from there.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BenjaminV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4952/benjaminv/) on 2013-05-23**:
Ok for the package version but still, I have already tried from sources, and it's not working (see the Ogre error)